# Store Image in Localstorage from Firebase-Storage and Get the Path

Tags: android, local-storage, firebase-storage

I have images stored in firebase storage. Now I want to get the image from storage, download it in local storage and save the path for future use.

What i have tried is:

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference httpsReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://****.appspot.com/image_pics/" + userID + ".jpg");

//images are saved with named based on the userid of the user plus an extension of jpg
```

Now I want to use the `httpsReference` to download the image in local storage and return the path (in string).

I dont know whether I should use the storage location in firebase db (i.e. the gs// ...) or the url for what I want to do.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will help you to Save the File in Local Storage

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference httpsReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://****.appspot.com/image_pics/" + userID + ".jpg"); // IF this is working for you
```

or

```
StorageReference  myStorage = storageRef.child("file.txt"); // Use this and provide the reference
File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name");
        if(!rootPath.exists()) {
            rootPath.mkdirs();
        }
final File localFile = new File(rootPath,"imageName.txt");
islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Log.e("firebase local tem file created  created " + localFile.toString());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please modify your changes and ill accept your changes